# Qt - Stylesheet for custom button on mouse hovered and clicked

Tags: qt, button, stylesheet

I would like to have an invisible button, but when the user hovers the mouse on it, I would like to have a light blue color, and when he clicks it, I would like to have a darker blue.

After I did some research, I figured out I can use the stylesheets feature, but im new on Qt and I don't have any experience on Qt, so I would prefer to ask and learn.

Comment: What have you got for a stylesheet so far? The qt stylesheet reference should have gotten you started, right?

Comment: I've got this:                                                         QPushButton {
        background-color: red (170,0,0);
        padding: 3px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 3px;
        border-color: red (120,0,0);
        border-radius: 40px;

    }
     
    QPushButton:pressed {
        background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
        background-position: top center;
border:visible;
    }

   QPushButton:hovered {
        background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
        background-position: top center;
    }

Comment: Currently, the button is invisible until hovered or clicked, but when I hover or click on it (I know... the color is redish, not bluish), the button is shown as a standard button (with the theme drawn on it), I do understand a very little of stylesheets, i'm still learning them

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
yourBtn->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background:url(:/Resources/pause_nor.png);border:0px;}"
    "QPushButton:hover{background:url(:/Resources/pause_over.png);border:0px}"
    "QPushButton:pressed{background:url(:/Resources/pause_over.png); position: relative;top: 1px; left: 1px;}");
```