# how to use mousePressEvent on QPushButtons

Tags: c++, qt

I've made some QPushbuttons like QPushButton **btn and I want to know when the user clicks on one of them using QMouseEvent here is the code but this idea does not work at all any ideas??

void Game::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{

```
if(ev->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
{
    btn[ev->x()][ev->y()].setStyleSheet("background-color : black;");
}
else
{
   btn[ev->x()][ev->y()].setStyleSheet("background-color : red;");
}
```

that else part is for right click
and here is the code that generates the buttons

```
void Game::MakeButton()
{

    btn = new ApButton*[column];
    hrztl = new QHBoxLayout[column];
    hrztl->setSpacing(0);
    for(int i=0; i<column;i++)
    {
        btn[i] = new ApButton[row];
        for(int j=0; j<row; j++)
        {
            btn[i][j].setRowCol(i,j);
            btn[i][j].setFixedSize(50,50);
            hrztl[i].addWidget(&btn[i][j]);
        }
        ui->MainLayout->addLayout(&hrztl[i]);
    }
    ui->MainLayout->setSpacing(0);
}
```

ApButton is a class that inherits QPushButton

Comment: Have you tried connecting the `clicked` signal to a slot for handling clicks? Perhaps you should handle your logic this way and reference a pointer to the button that you clicked to change the background color.

Comment: Why not use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292592/qt-stylesheet-for-custom-button-on-mouse-hovered-and-clicked ?

Comment: my problem in not in style sheet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch your

```
Game::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
```

to

```
ApButton::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
```

since you are trying to implement the Press Event of the Button. If you only want to have the moment of the button being pressed and not changing Button behaviour with this, use a SIGNAL/SLOT connection instead of reimplementing the event (add to your creation):

```
connect(btn[i][j], SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(slotButtonPressed());

void Game::slotButtonPressed(){
    //doSomething
}
```

use a QButtonGroup or the QSignalMapper if you need to identify more then one Button in a single method or use QObject::sender(), but this can be tricky sometimes.

Comment: how do I declare i and j. do you suggest that I put this connect function in my loop??

Comment: If you want all your buttons to behave like this, put it in your ApButton-Class ``mousepressevent(*e){ QPushButton::mousePressEvent(e); setStylesheet("Somtehing"); //doSomeMore}``. If you want just some buttons being changed by game logic if they are pressed, use a signal/slot connection. Put the ``connect()`` call in your loop and add a slot (method under ``slots:`` area in class definition) to your class. In this slot make the changes you want. Generally: Option 1) The button itself will decide when to style itself. Option 2) The parent class (Game) will tell the button to change.

Comment: With connect() (Signal/Slot) you do not neccesarily need to subclass QPushButton. If your buttons will generally behave different you probably still want to subclass and use a ApButton-included method for automatically changing the style itself. If you only need the pressed/toggled/released event you can also use a SIGNAL/SLOT connection in your ApButton class and change the work in there. Overwiting the ``mousePressEvent(*e)`` method would be useful if you intend another behaviour than the standard pressed/released/clicked/toggled action.

Comment: well I want to use right click as well.so I guess I have to use mousePressEvent...

Answer (score 2):

This is a good example of use for a [QSignalMapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsignalmapper.html), as seen there: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsignalmapper.html#details

```
ButtonWidget::ButtonWidget(QStringList texts, QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);

    QGridLayout *gridLayout = new QGridLayout;
    for (int i = 0; i < texts.size(); ++i) {
        QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(texts[i]);
        connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
        signalMapper->setMapping(button, texts[i]);
        gridLayout->addWidget(button, i / 3, i % 3);
    }

    connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)),
            this, SIGNAL(clicked(QString)));

    setLayout(gridLayout);
}
```

In that example, every button is identified by its title, as a QString. The mapper allows you to retrieve the corresponding button's title when one of them is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situations some times ago.. I had a QDialog and I had to dinamically add some QPushButton.. then I need to know on which button the user pressed.. so I needed something like:

```
connect( btn, SIGNAL( clicked(int) ),
         this, SLOT( handle(int) ));
```

for instance a signal-slot connection with the id of the clicked button and a function for handle the click. The function is the same for each buttons and can handle the specific button because of the id..

Implementing this is quite simple subclassing QPushButton adding an id and a new signal..

Hope it's some help!

Comment: thanks but what is that int in clicked and handle do you mean that I put the same integer in both as an id??and notice that my ApButton is **btn...

Comment: yes an integer as an id. and you can use a std::vector<QPushbutton*>

Comment: well the other problem is that I want to use right click too and I guess it's not possible with connect function...

Comment: why not? you have to write a `MyQPushbutton` class writing your signal for this left-click, override `mousePressEvent`, check for left button, and emit the signal with the id..

Answer (score 0):

If Apbutton inherits QPushButton, why don't connect to clicked()?

then you can call [QObject::sender()](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qobject.html#sender)

On slot:

```
ApButton *but = dynamic_cast<ApButton*>QObject::sender()
if(but)
{
   but->setStyleSheet("background-color : black;");
}
```

to get the clicked buttonbutton and set its stylesheet